# File only to e downloaded on specific page

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website with files that should only be downloaded from the download.php file, their saved in a map like /uploads/map1_/file.bin

I don't want people to be able to download the file directly from the directory but only from the download page. I think this is possible with htacces, but I can't find how to do that..

Comment: In which folder is your htaccess ? Do you want to disallow access to `uploads` folder or only `map1_` ? Do you have other `map` folders ?

Comment: Yes the map folders are also unpredictable, their always random. This is how it would look like: /uploads/sCkawSDk29c/file.bin an I only want them to be able to download it from download.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a `.htaccess` file in your `/uploads/` folder.
Then, put this code into it

```
<FilesMatch "\.bin$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from All
</FilesMatch>

Options -Indexes
```

Note: the most secure solution is to put your `bin` files **out** of public scope